# Subtract columns [i] row from very last row in r

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I am currently working with Monthly data. I have 10 columns and 200 rows. I want to subtract each consecutive row from the very last row in r. Is there a way to do this for all columns in a simple code? My current method is subtracting each column row from its maximum lag. For example total rows=200, so last row is row 200. My formula is columnB(i)-lag(columB,200).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `mtcars` dataset (which has no character or factor columns) as an example you could do:

```
mtcars - c(tail(mtcars, 1))
```